# How to start a bootlooping phone in Safe Mode

Tags: boot-loop

Exactly a week today, I updated Podcast Addict on my Alcatel One Touch M'pop 5020D. It shut down immediately I opened it. And then other apps started shutting down too. So before going to bed I restarted the cell. I woke up at dawn to realize it was stuck in bootloop. 
I've tried wiping the cache partition and performing a factory reset in Recovery Mode, but that hasn't helped. Fortunately or unfortunately (I'm currently in a state of confusion as to whether or not this was a good decision after all) my phone is not rooted. I therefore can not apply several options in fixing this. I'd like to know if there's any way, any medium at all, that I can boot into Safe Mode so I can uninstall the Podcast Addict. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you have a working ADB bridge in your recovery you can uninstall the app, more information can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949609/adb-shell-command-to-make-android-package-uninstall-dialog-appear).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the disappointing news, but there is no way to boot into safe mode without USB debugging enabled and already authorized by Android, and  root access or a custom recovery.

The content of the file named [`persist.sys.safemode`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/131224/96277) must be set to `1` for the device to boot into safe mode. The file is located under `/data/property`, is  owned by root user and is part of root group only. If only the root privileges are granted, the file can be edited.