# Difference between /system/build.prop properties and setprop persist.adb.tcp.port (example) properties?

Tags: settings, file-properties

What is the difference between properties manipulated in /system/build.prop file and properties manipulated by setprop, for example setprop persist.adb.tcp.port? Where is the latter property stored? Is there another properties file somewhere?

Comment: There is no difference between editing a property via a text editor and via `setprop`, although I don't know where **persist.adb.tcp.port** is stored.

Comment: Me neither though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your 2 last questions, according to several sources ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310809/where-does-ansroid-os-systemproperties-store-its-key-values), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440945/unsetting-persistent-system-properties), [3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131188/entering-safe-mode-from-adb-shell/131224#131224)), thoses are stored in `/data/property/`. I couldn't find an offical reference about this location though.

For you, that would be in `/data/property/persist.adb.tcp.port`.