# How does safe mode work?

Tags: safe-mode

I know what safe mode does: it disables all user installed apps while it's activated.

However, I wish to know more about its internal mechanism and how and when in the boot process it is implemented.

Comment: Slightly related info can be found in my answer and the comments therewith. http://android.stackexchange.com/a/131224/96277