# How to exit and disable safe mode?

Tags: samsung, 6.0-marshmallow, safe-mode

I have a Note 2 running a custom Android 6 ROM and it's stuck in safe mode.  It got stuck in safe mode once before, but I don't recall what I did to fix it.  I did have a sticky power button then, so I might have just cleaned it with alcohol pads.  At the time, I looked for a way to disable it.  Now I am stuck, due to the hubris of some programmers, which seems to be the norm for software nowadays /rant.

Articles online look like keyword stuffed AI generated articles, and simply are press releases for the feature, telling you how wonderful it is, how to enter it, and in Android 10, how you can exit it from a persistent notification.  Even the answers here are very similar.

I don't think I have a stuck button this time.  I've wiped cache in TWRP.  TWRP can't shutdown though, it just reboots into itself, which I think is odd.

The phone was having an issue where the power button was working for a double press, but not a single press or long press, and when I rebooted it to clear the issue, now I have a larger issue.

I have rebooted (many times), pulled the battery and let it sit (up to 8 hours), changed the battery, done a software reboot, cleared the Dalvik cache in TWRP, and searched online for some way to exit safe mode.

I can't just reformat and reinstall because I have apps with settings I would need to back up, like my contacts, and some secure apps that need to be backed up within the app.

1. How can I forcibly exit safe mode?
2. How can I disable safe mode permanently?

Comment: Did you try pulling out the battery and reboot after a while

Comment: Yes, with lengthening amounts of time, up to ~8 hours.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/131224/131553) which talks of getting out of safe mode. This is by Firelord, who is a moderator here and he would see this question